# separate 8th field

Tags: printing, awk, field, pipe, separator

I could not separate my file:

```
chr2    215672546   rs6435862   G   T   54.00   LowDP;sb DP=10;TI=NM_000465;GI=BARD1;FC=Silent   ...   ...
```

I would like to print first seven fields and from 8th field print just `DP=10` and `GI=BARD1`. `DP` in `GI` info is always in 8th field. Fields are continue (...) so 8th field is not last.

I know how to extract 8th field :

```
awk '{print $8}' PLZ-10_S2.vcf  | awk -F ";" '/DP/ {OFS="\t"} {print $1}'
```

of course how to extract first seven fields, but how to pipe it together? Between all fields is `tab`.

Answer (score 2):

If DP= and GI= are always in the same position within $8:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {split($8,a,/;/); $8=a[1]";"a[3]} 1' file
chr2    215672546       rs6435862       G       T       54.00   LowDP;sb       DP=10;GI=BARD1   ...     ...
```

If not:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {split($8,a,/;/); $8=""; for (i=1;i in a;i++) $8 = $8 (a[i] ~ /^(DP|GI)=/ ? ($8?";":"") a[i] : "")} 1' file
chr2    215672546       rs6435862       G       T       54.00   LowDP;sb       DP=10;GI=BARD1   ...     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to `split()` with semicolon the eight field and traverse all results to check which of them begin with `DP` or `GI`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

    { 
        split( $8, arr8, /;/ )
        $8 = "" 
        for ( i = 1; i <= length(arr8); i++ ) {
            if ( arr8[i] ~ /^(DP|GI)/ ) { 
                $8 = $8 arr8[i] ";" 
            }
        }
        $8 = substr( $8, 1, length($8) - 1 )
        print $0
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
chr2    215672546   rs6435862   G   T   54.00   LowDP;sb    DP=10;GI=BARD1  ... ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I expect that `$8 = substr( $8, 1, length($8) - 1 )` could give you a run-time error if neither DP nor GI appear in $8 because you'll be subtracting 1 from the length of an empty string which I expect is zero and, if so, trying to use `-1` as the 3rd arg for `substr()`.

Comment: @EdMorton: I've just tested it with a modified version of the input and it doesn't complain (or faster with something like `substr($80, 1, -1)`). Simply doesn't print nothing. Then there would be two joined `tabs` in output and field eigth would be the current ninth, but it's a possible bug that I hope the OP will know how to handle (or at least know how to ask in another thread :-)

Comment: I just tried it on a couple of different awks and they didn't complain either, except for gawk with the `--lint` flag on which produced `gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: substr: length -1 is <= 0`. I don't know if all awks will behave the same way, the POSIX spec might say something about it, idk. Two joined tabs in the output are not a problem, there's still a null 8th field between them